# Is there a way to auto-generate Record Type classes in C# from Json file, using Visual Studio, as it was the "Paste Special" option?

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio, c#-record-type

I'm working on a small (net6 - C# 10) converter project which has a class used for Json deserialization.
This class is auto-generated from a web site, and I'd like to use the same (or similar) structure offline for additional changes to the structure.

The generated class is something like the code below:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public record Root([property: JsonPropertyName("otherRecordClass")] OtherRecordType OtherRecordType);        
}
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2022, in the past projects I just used to copy the Json code and paste it using "Paste Special" to create the class structure, but it does not use the **record types**. Is there any way to do it? I'm pretty new to the "record type" world, I hope someone can suggest a solution.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you think that records are  better then classes? Records are simplified variant of classes that doesn't have a lot o features, it is made only to decrease typing in some cases. And in the most cases  the records doesn't fit for application development.

Comment: Wrong @Serge. Just plain wrong. Records implement value-based equality out of the box, as well as brought along the `init` keyword for initialize only properties

Comment: @AdamVincent What  new features records have that classes don't have ? Records were made by novice developers for novice developers that can't  learn how to create classes

Comment: I just told you. Value-Based Equality.  Not having to write boiler plate for immutable classes, or value-object implementations is a huge improvement. Here are more details. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/records

Comment: @AdamVincent It is the same as typescript and javascript.  A compiler converts type scripts into javascripts. The same way it is here. Compiler converts records to classes that takes extra steps, so it effects a compiler performance.

Comment: JavaScript is not a compiled language. Typescript is `transpiled` into JavaScript.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246733/discussion-between-adam-vincent-and-serge).

Comment: Hi Serge and Adam Vincent, thank you for the answers. We used it because it was a easy and faster to implement code. It's not our main project, and we used it exactly because we can use value-based equality. I just was wondering if is there a way to auto-generate it offline, without sharing potential sensitive data to a web site.

Comment: I just did it, thank you! Unfortunately I can see that 2 years has passed since the request was posted, I would have appreciated it a lot these days. If I find some offline alternatives in the meantime I will post it here.